# Return value from the controller of child modal to the controller of parent modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I have two states in my application. In each of these states I open a modal dialogs, that has their own controllers: `parentCtrl` and `childCtrl`. I wanna return to the parent modal in `select(config)` function and return `config` value to the parent state, just into `parentCtrl`.

```
$stateProvider.state('parent', {
                url: "...",
                onEnter: function ($stateParams, $state, $uibModal) {
                    $uibModal.open({
                        templateUrl:  '...',
                        controller: function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
                            ...
                        },
                        controllerAs: 'parentCtrl'
                    });
                }           
        }); 

$stateProvider.state('parent.child', {
                url: "...",
                onEnter: function ($stateParams, $state, $uibModal) {
                    $uibModal.open({
                        templateUrl:  '...',
                        controller: function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
                            this.select = function (config) {
                                debugger;
                                alert("Hall:"+ config.hallName+", configuration:"+ config.name+", configId: "+ config.id);
                                $uibModalInstance.close({data: config});
                            };
                        },
                        controllerAs: 'childCtrl'
                    }).result.finally(function () {
                        debugger;
                        $state.go('^');
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: you can use a service to store the 'config' and share the service in both controller

Comment: @Alainlb, I hoped there is some solution out of box. Using service to store value looks for me like a sort of global variable.

Comment: each service is a singleton who are not reinitialised on each controller change. the service content still the same ( unless you edit it ) during all the app life

Answer (score 1):

For bootstrap modals, the modal scope will be a child of the controller's scope and in angular scope are chained.

So if you initialize your parent controller with : 
    $scope.modal = {};
    $scope.modal.newData = function(data){};

You should be able to do in modal controller : 
    $scope.modal.newData (data);

Note : the intermediary object modal is because of the limit of scope inheritance, you may have not problem with this javascript but you may have with templating so i always use interdiary objects when playing around with scope inheritance.

EDIT : didn't see it was for 2 independant modals. The best would be to use what i post and to close and open again the parent modal from parent scope data in order to refresh it.

Otherwise you can emit/listen for events in angularjs using $scope/$rootScope.$on/$emit.

For this kind of stuff, use $rootScope.$on to listen, and $rootScope.emit to send event.

Answer (score 1):

The result of your child modal can pass parameters.

```
.result.then(function (data) {
     $state.go('^', data);
});
```

this data is the parameter you entered in the .close() operation. You can catch those params in your state config, through adding the following on your parent state definition

```
params: {
        data: {}
    }
```

Comment: Yes, this way allows me to put data into `$stateParams`. But after returning from child modal I have to call some callback function, that will put value from $stateParams to my `parentCtrl` variable.